# read into variable from cut command but without having to write data to a file

Tags: bash, cut

I want to read the output of a cut command into a variable but without having to go through the intermediate step of writing to a file.

This is my how I do it now:

```
echo "001.002.003.004">out.txt
var1=$(cut -d '.' -f 1,2 out.txt)
```

but I have the "001.002.003.004" string in a variable $fullversion.  How can I use the env variable from cut without generating a file?

Comment: `cut -d '.' -f 1,2 <<< "$fullversion"`

Comment: var1=$(echo "001.002.003.004" | cut -d '.' -f 1,2)

Comment: While the comment by anubhava certainly describes the general approach to your problem, I don't understand why you want to use `cut` for this task. A `var1=${fullversion%.*.*}` should work equally well, and no childprocess is created.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use an array

```
data="001.002.003.004"

arr=(${data//./ }) # will create an array of (001 002 003 004)
printf -v var1 '%s.%s' "${arr[@]:0:2}" # will create var1="001.002"
```